# The name 'ViewH' does not exist in the current context (C#)

Tags: c#

Hi I just started C# and I ran into this problem. Below is my code. I'm trying to have ViewH be displayed but it sends me an error that it does not exist in the current context. I'm not sure what it's asking.

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Ranger r1 = new Ranger();
        ViewH(r1);
       // ViewV();
    }
}
```

This is where it is linked.

```
class View
{
    public void ViewH()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name       Health       Endurance      Bonus       Tool");
        Console.WriteLine("_______________________________________________________");

    }
    public void ViewV()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name:   ");
        Console.WriteLine("Health:   ");
        Console.WriteLine("Endurance:   ");
        Console.WriteLine("Bonus:   ");
        Console.WriteLine("Tool:   ");

    }
}
```

Comment: `ViewH` is an instance method on a different class.  You'll need to instantiate that class to call its method.

Comment: I see a couple issues: there is no ViewH method that takes a Ranger as a parameter, and you either need the ViewH method to be static or you need to create an instance of the View class so you can call View.ViewH.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to call a method from another class, you have two options:

1. The method is an instance method, i.e., it doesn't have a `static` modifier: you must instantiate the class (create an object with `new`) and then call the method on the object:

   ```
   var view = new View();
   view.ViewH(); // Note that ViewH is declared without a parameter,
                 // so we can't pass it an argument.
   ```
2. The method is static, i.e., it has a `static` modifier: call the method on the type name:

   ```
   View.ViewH();
   ```

An instance method can access other instance members of the class like fields, properties or other methods. Each instance, i.e., each object created from it, has its own set of values stored in fields and properties. On the other hand, static fields and properties exist exactly once.

If all members of a class are static, you can mark the class itself as static. This makes it clear, that no instances can be created with `new`.

Only non-static classes can inherit from other classes an implement interfaces.

See also:

- [Inheritance (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance)
- [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)
- [Static and instance members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#static-and-instance-members) in the article [Classes (Language reference, C# 6.0 draft specification)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes)